# SDL2 floating point audio doesn't clip

Tags: audio, floating-point, sdl, clipping

I'm generating a 440Hz sine wave in 32bit floating point audio format with SDL2.

I've read [else where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181316/32-bit-float-mono-audio-in-jack) that 32bit floating point audio format is normalised between -1.0 and +1.0.

With that statement I would expect clipping to occur for values beyond -1 and +1.

as I increase the amplitude of the sine wave beyond -1.0 and +1.0, the tone becomes loader (really really loud at 3000 amplitude), and no clipping seems to occur.

so my questions are:

- what is happening with amplitudes beyond -1.0/+1.0 and why doesn't it clip?
- what is the maximum amplitude value in 32bit floating point audio format?
- Is there anywhere that defines the -1/+1 normalisation convention?

Answer (score 3):

When converting from integer formats to floating point, SDL maps to [-1, 1], however when mixing it clips at max `float`: [-3.402823466e+38F, 3.402823466e+38F].

Apart from this, SDL appears to pass float audio data through directly to its many audio device implementations unmodified, so your question becomes operating system/audio card specific.

In your case, your signal has probably been "logarithmed" at some point, hence the lack of clipping at 3000x.

Comment: ok, sounds like my question should be "how does core audio treat floating point audio?"

Comment: I think as I said above, e.g. read here: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-10-26-fourier-transforms-and-ffts.html